# Jagged Images with CSS 3D-Transforms on Windows XP

Tags: firefox, css, css-transforms

I have a problem with 3D-Transforms on Images. 
For example:

```
transform: rotateY(60deg);
```

It works fine everywhere except Firefox on Windows XP. The image is displayed jagged there (no anti-aliasing?). It looks nice with Safari, Chrome and with Firefox on Windows 7 and Mac OS X. Also tested different versions of Firefox with no other results.

I couldn't find any description or solution of the same problem. Some write that giving a (transparent) border/outline helps to improve the edges but it doesn't help inside the image.

I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8Tx6X/4/

Here is how it looks in Firefox 16.0.1 on Windows 7 (and other browsers) compared to Firefox 16.0.1 on Windows XP:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NePyd.png

Anyone experienced the same behaviour?

Could it be a problem with hardware/software-rendering?
(I tested on XP with a virtual machine and an old laptop)

I would love to find a hack or at least a way to detect if it is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more investigation brought me a little bit further. It's not a problem with Windows XP as I thought first. The problem occurs if Firefox doesn't use hardware acceleration. When I turn that off (in Options -> Advanced -> General -> Use hardware acceleration when available), it looks jagged on Windows 7 too. I also tested on another computer with WinXP where the image looks fine. You can see if Firefox is using hardware acceleration when you type in "about:support" and look for "WebGL Renderer" and "GPU Accelerated Windows".

So I guess Firefox's software renderer can't do any better right now.

What I do now is detect if WebGL is activated and therefore hardware acceleration is available. This is the code I use (it's from an old version of Modernizr):

```
try {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),ret;
    ret = !!(window.WebGLRenderingContext && (canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl') || canvas.getContext('webgl')));
        canvas = undefined;
} catch (e){
    ret = false;
}
return ret;
```

If the test passes I serve CSS-3D-Transforms. Otherwise the user sees a flash fallback.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue, with Firefox on Windows 7. As you say the edges can be fixed but the content, (I have not used an image, but absolutely positioned HTML elements) looks terrible, but in Chrome and Safari they are fine.